# Memory location being displayed instead of str in python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am new to python and programming in general. I am trying to read letters and write them in upper case with the program ending when a digit is introduced.
I have come up with the following lines of code:

```
while True:
    a=input('Type letter to be capitalised ')
    digit=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7','8','9', '0']
    if a not in digit:
       a=a.upper
       print("The upper case of your character is {}".format(a))
    else:
       break
```

However, when I run the code, i do not get the upper case character instead i get:

```
"The upper case of your character is <built-in method upper of str object at 0x109eedab0>"
```

I do not want the memory location of my output. I want the output to be printed on the screen.Can someone please show me where the error is?

Comment: You have to call the method: `a = a.upper()`

Comment: @SergeBallesta or `a = a.upper()` :)

Comment: Thanks! @KlausD. It work! :)

Comment: Thanks! @Serge Ballesta

Comment: note that you can use `a.isalpha()` to detect if it's a letter (or `a.isdigit()`). Python is not asm or Fortran, there's a lot of excellent methods attached to each base object, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jean-FrançoisFabre! This is very helpful!